# curl error 23 using vagrant on OSX 10.10.5

Tags: linux, macos, curl

I'm using a Udacity class on linux shell commands. I'm using OSX 10.10.5. and I installed Ubuntu from Virtual Box (VirtualBox 5.0.20 for OS X hosts  amd64 from xxxs://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads as instructed.)

It uses this VM of Ubuntu, and Vagrant (from xxxs://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.8.1/vagrant_1.8.1.dmg) to connect that terminal to the VM.

Using this VM is for file consistency. Commands build on each other in the class.

One task (which is minor...and not graded) is to run the following command

```
curl xxx://udacity.github.io/ud595-shell/stuff.zip -o things.zip
```

[I can't post more than one link due to low reputation the xxx is http above.]

This command should hit the 'net and download a zip file named "things.zip". This fails for me, giving the below:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/$ curl http://udacity.github.io/ud595-shell/stuff.zip -o things.zip
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file things.zip: Permission denied
  0  144k    0   796    0     0   3241      0  0:00:45 --:--:--  0:00:45  3235
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 796)
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/$
```

---

So I get error 23 and am not sure why. (Googling is failing to answer this.) I'm guessing there is a permission error but not sure where to start.

Comment: If you `cd /tmp` and try it there does it work. If so you don't have permissions to the directory it needs to write to which looks like `/` in your example. If you are in `/` then you need to be root to write to it.

Comment: Thank you I cd'd to tmp, and it worked! I'm not entirely clear if when you say I should be in /  whether vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/$  counts as / it is the farthest back I can cd ..   my shell is very limited - hence the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing permissions from the directory you're in when downloading the file. You can check this by changing to a directory like `/tmp` and trying it there.